# how to install xcape on mac?

Tags: vim, keymapping

I'm recently learning to use VIM editor which is so great. Just as other vimmers, I find it's a little unpleasant to press the esc and ctrl key because they are a little far away. I find a solution is to map both esc and ctrl to caps lock with the help of [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape).

But I'm not sure how to install it. Because the homepage of xcape is using apt-get to install necessary packages. I think on mac, apt-get is not available. I have homebrew installed, however there's no xcape package on homebrew.

So I'm just not sure how to install xcape, could anyone help?
btw, how to make it work on windows?

Answer (score 2):

xcape will be of no use on a Mac. Try [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) instead.